# Convert (C), (R), (TM) and (o) to ©, ®, ™, ° repectively in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat6

I want to convert (C), (R), (TM) and (o) to ©, ®, ™, ° repectively.

I am replacing the string which contains the above mentioned characters with their respective symbols. Sample code snippet shown below

```
public static String convertSpecialCharacters( String source ){

     if( isNotEmpty( source ) ){
         source = source.replaceAll( "\\(o\\)", "°" ).replaceAll( "\\(C\\)", "©" ).replaceAll(  "\\(R\\)", "®" ).replaceAll( "\\(TM\\)", "™" );
     } 
}
```

when i pass the string "Sample text © ® ° ™" i get the following output.

"Sample Text ¬© ¬Æ ¬∞ ‚Ñ¢".

The symbols get converted as expected when i run on local machine but When i deploy the application on tomcat server i get the above output.

Is it something do with tomcat server?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What encoding is the page using on each server?

Comment: You're going need to tell how exactly you're presenting those characters to the enduser. Via a JSP file? By the way, `replaceAll()` is clumsy for this specific purpose. You don't need regex pattern matching at all, you just need string-by-string replacement. Just use `replace()` then. This way you also don't need to escape the parens.

Comment: The encoding of your editor must also be something known. When you type  © in the source file it is encoded into a byte sequence by the editor.  This encoding must match the encoding that you are using for the output on console, browser, etc.

Comment: @tbsalling I am using Eclipse IDE and the Text File encoding is set as UTF-8. I am using tomcat server 6 and the URI encoding is also set as UTF-8.

This problem is not reproducible on local machine. when i deploy on UAT server this issue occurs.

Comment: @BalusC I tried with replace method even still no chance.
My dev environment is in windows7 and the UAT environment is on linux. Would that be a cause for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue resolved. Instead of replacing the string with specific symbol replace with the unicode characters as shown below.

```
public static String convertSpecialCharacters( String source ) {          
     if( isNotEmpty( source ) ){
          source = source.replaceAll( "\\(o\\)", "\u00B0" ).replaceAll( "\\(C\\)", "\u00a9").replaceAll(  "\\(R\\)", "\u00AE" ).replaceAll( "\\(TM\\)", "\u2122" );
     } 
}
```

Comment: Thus, your concrete problem is that your Java source files themselves are not saved or read using UTF-8.

Comment: @BalusC yes the java source files was not read using UTF-8 even though the environment encoding is set to UTF-8